# Android - RecyclerView - How do I temporarily prevent scrolling?

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview, cancellation

I have a RecyclerView that I wish to freeze (ie, not allow the user to scroll, but still be able to tap any current visible views) until a certain condition is met. How do I achieve this?

I've tried to set an `OnScrollListener` as following:

```
@Override
public void onScrolled(final RecyclerView recyclerView, final int dx, final int dy) {

     super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

     if(myCondition){
         recyclerView.stopScroll();
     }
});
```

without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out. `OnItemTouchListener` should be used instead:

```
onItemTouchListener = new OnItemTouchListener() {

      @Override
      public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(final RecyclerView recyclerView, final MotionEvent e) {

          if(myCondition){

              switch(e.getAction()){

                  case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: return true;
              }
          }

          return false;
      }

      @Override
      public void onTouchEvent(final RecyclerView recyclerView, final MotionEvent e) {
      }
};
```

Now you add it to your RecyclerView:

```
yourRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(onItemTouchListener);
```

If anyone finds an easier way, please, let me know!